# How to Management Elasticsearch Index data

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I am using Elasticsearch to search for products.

Perform full indexing of product information on a daily basis.

I am deleting and recreating the index for clean indexing, but I am not sure how to handle product search at that time.

How about the standard way of handling queries at the time of clean full indexing?

During clean full indexing, I thought about processing it logically through a status check after creating a completely new index, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of doing it is by using an alias. You have the current product index, let's call it `products-1` and it is aliased with the name `products`. All your search queries go through the alias name and not through the index name.

When you need to reindex your products, you do so but in a new index called `products-2` and when you're done indexing and tested that everything went fine, you just switch the alias using the following command and your search queries will be carried out uninterrupted:

```
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "remove": {
        "index": "products-1",
        "alias": "products"
      }
    },
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "products-2",
        "alias": "products"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can then go ahead and delete the index or if you're confident you can do it in a single step like this:

```
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "remove_index": {
        "index": "products-1"
      }
    },
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "products-2",
        "alias": "products"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I'll have to test it out right away.